# Gremlin: Unexpected result when using coalesce with group().by()

Tags: gremlin

I'm trying to group vertices and for each, get the sum of a property value.

I'd like to get `0` if the value doesn't exist so I need to add a `coalesce` in the following query (from Modern graph):

```
g.V().group().by(__.label()).by(__.out("knows").values("age").sum())
==>[person:59]
```

But with the `coalesce` step, the result is not what I expect (`[software:0,person:59]`):

```
g.V().group().by(__.label()).by(__.coalesce(__.out("knows").values("age").sum(), __.constant(0)))
==>[software:0,person:0]
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are grouping by `label` and a `person` has both `knows` and `created` edges. So The `person` is matching with the `constant(0)` first due to the `created` edges.

```
gremlin> g.V().outE().inV().path().by(label)
==>[person,created,software]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,knows,person]
==>[person,created,software]
==>[person,created,software]
==>[person,created,software]
```